# Facebook OG Image seen as too big

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Facebook debugger says that my image file is too big :

> Provided og:image URL, http://api-wp.quebecsolidaire.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/QS-OG.jpg could not be downloaded because it exceeded the maximum allowed sized of 8Mb.

But if you check the mentioned file, its weight is 97.9Ko ...

Comment: Still having the issue with a 2.26kb image...

Answer (score 0):

I just checked two sites where I am sure that the images were set up correctly.

For both the FB-Debugger tells me:

> The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value
>   can be inferred from other tags.

It seems to me, as if they have a problem with their og:image-tool – I advice to wait.

Especially if you see a correct **Link Preview** except their warning, like I do.